# input number depended option show

Tags: javascript, html

In my page, I asked the number of the player which will next ask team number now I want when player number more than 12 then option show team . but my script only when I put 12 it work not work for more than 12

```
<div class="form-group">  <label for="player">Total Number of Player:</label> <input type ="number"class="form-control" id="player" name="player" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'required>
    </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
function CheckColors(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('team');
 if(val=='12')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script><br>
  <div  class="form-group">  <label for="team">Number of Team:</label> <select class="form-control" id="team" name="team" style='display:none;'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option> 3</option>
  </select> </div>
```

Now please help to solve my problem or correction my script.
and it's control my option only I want if input number below 12 then total team div also not show

Comment: `if (+val >= 12)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using a wrong condition. Try this:

```
function CheckColors(val){
    var element=document.getElementById('team');
    if( val >= 12 )
        element.style.display='block';
    else  
        element.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: thanks .Ok it's work now , please help to control the view of team div and i want to if number is divided by 11 then option show  for example if 22 then option show 1 & 2 , if 17 then team option show only 1